# Solving $8^{2x}-2\cdot8^x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$8^{2x}-2\cdot8^x+1=0$, I tried a lot of ways to solve this equation, like changing $8$ to $2^3$, or writing $2*8^x$ as $2*2^{3x}$ and then $2^{3x+1}$, but i'm not getting anywhere, i have the solution which is $x=0$, but i don't know how to get there. Thanks.

Comment: What about $y=8^x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So you can let $8^x = a$
>
> #### $$8^{2x} -2(8^x)+1 = 0 $$
>
> $$ (8^x)^2 - 2(8^x) + 1 = 0$$ 
>   $$ a^2 -2a +1 = 0 $$
>   $$ (a-1)^2 = 0$$
>   $$a = 1 $$ 
>   $$ 8^x = 1 = 8^0$$
>
> #### $$x = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

let $8^x=y$. The equation becomes $y^2-2y+1=(y-1)^2=0$ and so $y-1=0$ and we get $8^x=1$ and hence $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Reduce your exponential equation to a quadratic equation via $$ y = 8^x$$ to get

$$ y^2 - 2y+1 = 0 .$$